# Linq with critera for nested list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested list of the following class:

```
public class ClassD 
{
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public List<StructKeyValuePair<string, string>> StructKeyValPairs { get; set; }
}

public class StructKeyValuePair<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }
    public V Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have `List<ClassD> resultList` and need to check if there is a row with this condition in that list:

```
EnDate > today
Key == "Key1" and Value != "Value1"
Key == "Key2" and Value == "Value2"
```

I need to return `true` or `false` depending on whether this criteria is met. Is there an easy way to do this using Linq in single line vs using nested loops?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Actually he did if you view the edit history

Comment: Um, why aren't you using KeyValuePair, why is your Struct really a class?

Comment: @Gary.S: How precisely does one do that? I have tried in the past, and can only do it for my own posts.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens just click on the link above the editors name (the time since last edit)

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Withdrawn; thank you.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, once you hit a certain rep you will be able to edit other peoples questions.

Comment: @Gary.S: Thank you; it's a good day when I learn something new, an even better one when I learn several new things.

Comment: @AbeMiessler: Well past that rep; just didn't know about the additional link in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this, using the Linq `Any`:

```
bool condition = resultList.Any(row => 
    row.EndDate > DateTime.Today 
    && row.StructKeyValPairs.Any(kvp => kvp.K == "Key1" && kvp.V != "Value1")
    && row.StructKeyValPairs.Any(kvp => kvp.K == "Key2" && kvp.V == "Value2")
);
```

This returns true if there is a row with all of (not sure if I guessed right at the exact logic):

1. EndDate > today
2. any KVP with "Key1" and not "Value1"
3. any KVP with "Key2" and "Value2"